# Wiki that allows syncing and merge conflict resolving

Tags: open-source, wiki, synchronization

*As I haven’t yet found a [wiki (with local server) that can sync encrypted (with untrusted online server)](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/36049/60), I’m now trying to connect several pieces together myself.*

I’m looking for a wiki (free/libre & self-hosted) that allows

- **syncing** with an online location
- resolving of **merge conflicts**

In case of merge conflicts, it would ideally be possible to see a colored diff within the wiki.

Only the most basic wiki features are needed: editing text, linking pages.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to achieve this is to use a static page site generator of which there are a great many. [Ghost](https://ghost.org/) for example is aimed at a blog style, GitBook is more of a notebook style. DocPad might be more suited to your needs.

There is a site that lists some of the top static site generators at https://www.staticgen.com/

You can use local tools to help build the site and you typically use a build command that produces a set of output files that you simply sync to a suitable host. GitHub for example. All you need is a source control tool such as Git. The source control tool will manage any conflicts and since the output is text files (html), any conflicts are easy to work through, even line-by-line if needed.

Comment: A consequence of this is that I won’t be able to edit where I read (i.e., in the browser), right? So when reading the wiki in the browser, and I want to edit something, I have to find the file corresponding to the page, edit the file with a text editor, save it, generate the site, switch back to the browser, and reload the page. With this process, it wouldn’t really be a wiki anymore. -- Or are there SSG that come with a web interface for editing/generating?

Comment: OK, if you need to edit online as well, you will need something that handles that and a suitable server environment for handling the online updates. Not impossible. You might look at something like TiddlyWiki which has both online and offline versions using text files as the backend. Or, if using GitHub or similar, the online file editor would do the job with git still handling the sync.